# juntar dos tablas

Tags: sql

Amigos una consulta en una tabla tengo un valor único por registros

**Tabla_collar**

```
bhid       largo(m) 
dd-001     100
```

en otra tabla tengo

**tabla_survey**

```
bhid        profundidad(m) 
dd-001      0 
dd-001      50 
dd-001      99.9
```

Necesito que me aparezca en una tabla lo siguiente:

```
bhid      largo      profundidad 
dd-001    100        99
```

He intentado con `left join` y también con las subconsultas, además he puesto a profundidad `max=(profundidad)` pero no me lo muestra hay alguien de buena voluntad que me pudiera ayudar

Comment: Agrega el codigo que hiciste para que te lo corrijan

Comment: También coloca el motor de base de datos que estas usando. Saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hacele caso a todos los comentarios.. esto es un join comun. mostra lo que probaste y no anduvo asi podemos ayudarte con tu problema en particular

Comment: ¿Por qué la profundidad es 99 y no 99.9 o 100? ¿Qué es es collar y survey? Se supone que los datos deberían tener un sentido antes de poder tratarlos...

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer un join con la subconsulta que obtiene el valor máximo (`MAX`) de la profundidad de cada `bhid`

```
SELECT a.bhid, b.profundidad
FROM Tabla_collar a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT bhid, MAX(profundidad) as profundidad
    GROUP BY bhid
) b on a.bhid = b.bhid
```

Comment: Roger... en serio? no mostro nada.. no sabemos para que base de datos... no sabemos porque no le anduvo el join.. me parece que te apuraste :(

Comment: No te voy a decir que no. Pero al editar la pregunta y formatearla vi la respuesta clara y no lo pensé más

Comment: claro, esta es la solucion, pero no la explicacion del problema.. asi como esta, no le sirve a nadie mas... solo a OP al cual le diste la solucion a su problema y nada mas...